# Data copy method direct assign vs memcpy in c

Tags: c, memcpy

I want to copy data from different variables and put it together in an array so that I can process it further.

I have studied direct assignment and memcpy method and think memcpy is used to copy complete buffer and not individual elements. Also I think it may take time and waste CPU cycles to use memcpy for individual bytes.

Can you please let me know from below example what should be used in such case since it is running in multithreaded environment(different example) and varibles may change?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{

    printf("Direct assign method\n");

    uint8_t pack_id = 123;
    uint8_t pack_age = 76;
    uint8_t pack_cmd = 30;

    uint8_t cus_data[3] = {0};

    cus_data[0] = pack_id;
    cus_data[1] = pack_age;
    cus_data[2] = pack_cmd;

    printf("Memcpy method\n");

    pack_id = 112;
    pack_age = 89;
    pack_cmd = 25;

    memcpy(&cus_data[0], &pack_id, sizeof(pack_id));
    memcpy(&cus_data[1], &pack_age, sizeof(pack_age));
    memcpy(&cus_data[2], &pack_cmd, sizeof(pack_cmd));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `memcpy` for one byte would probably take more time than direct assignment.

Comment: Choose the best readable version and leave the compiler to do the optimization. `memcpy()` looks inappropriate here, indeed.

Comment: @FiddlingBits or then not.

Comment: Modern compilers are likely to change the memcpy into an assignment.  If you can read assembly code, put this code into https://godbolt.org/ , or you can even just skim the assembly code and see that it doesn't call memcpy.

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong. If these variables *change* in a multithreaded program while doing the assignment then you have a *data race* and the behaviour of the program is *undefined*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. :-(

Comment: @FiddlingBits `memcpy` is a standard library function and the compiler is allowed to optimize as it pleases.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Gotcha.  Using one or the other may result in the same machine code, unless you disable optimization, right?

Comment: @FiddlingBits https://godbolt.org/z/U9PkwY everything is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cus_data[0] = pack_id;` is never slower than `memcpy(&cus_data[0], &pack_id, sizeof(pack_id));`. They may however be equally fast, if the compiler inlines the memcpy call, which is very likely.

What you should do instead of worrying about micro-optimizations is to write *the most readable code possible*. Worry about optimizations when you encounter actual performance problems.

Since `cus_data[0] = pack_id;` is the most readable, that's what you should be doing.

---

> in such case since it is running in multithreaded environment

Doesn't make a difference. Either you need to protect the variables against re-entrancy bugs, or you don't need to protect them. This has nothing to do with simple assignment vs memcpy, because neither of them are guaranteed to be atomic.

It doesn't matter how small/large the variables are, since nothing in the C language guarantees atomic access unless you use C11 `_Atomic` and similar.

Answer (score 4):

Practically every optimizing compiler (certainly gcc, clang, and icc) treats `memcpy` (and a handful of other libc functions, e.g., `memcmp`) as a builtin that's backed up by a real libc function of the same name.

Compilers will generally only call the real function iff doing the work with inline assembly looks like too much work.

Copying a character certainly doesn't fall in that category. These two generate the [same assembly with gcc/clang/icc](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CmQAzg):

```
#include <string.h> //compilers generally know about memcpy
//but C still requires that it should be prototyped

void assign_char(char *X)
{
    *X = 'x';
}

void memcpy_char(char *X)
{
    memcpy(X,"x",1);
}
```

x86_64 output:

```
 assign_char:
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], 120
        ret
 memcpy_char:
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], 120
        ret
```

It doesn't matter which one you use. The `memcpy` version is more generic (works on arrays too, even though arrays can't be assigned to/from in C) and allows you to circumvent strict aliasing, but it's also a bit more verbose to write.

Answer (score -1):

The most of modern computer's size of address is 8 bytes which 64bit.
You just do not assign a address which 8bytes into 1byte(8bit) storage variable.

for example 
memcpy(&cus_data[0], &pack_id, sizeof(uinit8_t*));

However, you did this below 3 times, for a sequence.
memcpy(&cus_data[0], &pack_id, sizeof(uinit8_t));

memcpy() func. is such as this

```
void memcpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t size) { 
char *c_src = (char *)src; 
char *c_dest = (char *)dest; 
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
    c_dest[i] = c_src[i];
```

}

It will copy src to dest 1byte by 1byte. and so on..

so, I like to use struct, case 1 instead of above
further case 2 code copy a pointer once.

```
struct PACK{
uint8_t id;
uint8_t age;
uint8_t cmd;
```

};

int main() {

```
struct PACK pack = { .id = 123, .age = 76, .cmd = 30 };
uint8_t cus_data[3];

// case 1
memcpy(cus_data, &pack, 3);

// case 2
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t*)&pack;


for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What has this to do with the question? Nobody is trying to write an addess into 1 byte anywhere.